# Parsing a text file in C

Tags: c, string, file, compare

I am making a program that displays the element of your choice from the periodic table using a file. I try to compare a string with a line of the  file, but it doesn't work. How can I fix the comparison?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char * line = NULL;
    char name_element[1000];
    size_t len=0;
    ssize_t read;

    FILE*table;
    table=fopen("Data.txt","r");

    printf("Please enter the element you are looking for:\n");
    scanf("%s",name_element);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, table))!=-1){
        i=strcmp(name_element,line);
        if  (strcmp(line,name_element)==0) {
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, table))!=-1) {
                if(strcmp(line,"////")!=0) {
                    printf("%s", line);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    fclose(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the format of Data.txt?

Comment: You do know you have a memory leak from the first `getline` call? And that the second call will use the existing buffer and its size so if the line is longer than the previous line not all will be read.

Comment: It would also help very much if you could show a sample of the input file.

Comment: I got it to work!! Thank you homie for the strncmp. I'll buy you a pizza when you're in the city

Comment: @PierreCasenave: Yeah, sorry, I deleted my original comment. I meant to erase a comment on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you may want to include the input file, just in case that is part of the problem.

Assuming that won't cause any problems, `strncmp()` is the way to go. The format is `strncmp(str1, str2, n)` where `n` is the number of characters you want to compare.

Comment: Yes I will remember that. Thank you so much for answering so fast!! And  btw it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getline()` which stores the `'\n'` that's why `strcmp()` is returning a non-zero value. Because `scanf()` doesn't include the `'\n'`.

Try

```
size_t length = sizeof(name_element);
getline(&name_element, &length, stdin);
```

and they should compare equal, but that will not solve the problem.

You need to remove the trailing `'\n'` from the line read from the file, because the last line might not contain the `'\n'` or use [this solution which is also good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31480771/1983495) because you may know the string length if you use the `"%n"` `scanf()` specifier.

Also, please check the return value from `scanf()` if you want your code to be robust.